# How to always open atom search results in split view?

Tags: atom-editor

By default, when atom displays search results it opens a new tab. However, what I always end up doing is opening split view and then closing the search results on the left tab so that only the right-side search results remain. Now, when I click on a result in the right-side it opens on the left side.

**Is there a way to tell atom to do this for me automatically?**

What I want is best illustrated with a screenshot, immediately after executing the search I want atom to look like this:

[image: goal]

Here is what I do currently:

[image: too-many-key-presses]

Comment: Note that only `Find in Project` opens the results in a new pane, the simple `Find in Buffer` does not seem to do that (unfortunately, on 1.16.0).

Answer (score 6):

It's a setting on the `find-and-replace` package. See here:

https://discuss.atom.io/t/find-results-as-a-panel-in-page-bottom/17136

Answer (score 3):

I think that this package can do what you want: [**project-find-navigation**](https://atom.io/packages/project-find-navigation).

[image: goal]
<sub>(source: [github-camo.com](https://i.github-camo.com/02979d52e3f37e080bf57330d6a6688a39806c1e/68747470733a2f2f7261772e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f74396d642f74396d642f353565376664333235303064343537353165326437383234663030386534326230363736336364312f696d672f61746f6d2d70726f6a6563742d66696e642d6e617669676174696f6e2e676966))</sub>

Google query: "Project Find Results" atom editor

Comment: I installed `project-find-navigation` but for the life of me I can't get this to actually work.

Comment: Weird... I tested in atom 1.0.3. Which version you're using?

Comment: I'm facing this similar issue, i tried using your soln..but didnt workk:( my version: 1.2.4